# Firefox 4: Dynamically opened window opens new tabs in old window (i.e. window.opener)

Tags: javascript, window, firefox4

This seems to be a strange change of functionality since Firefox 4. After opening a window with window.open(), when clicking links in the opened window with the middle mouse button (or right-clicking and selecting 'open in new tab') results in the link being opened in a new tab *in the old window*.

In Firefox 3, the tab would have opened in the new window.

Example code, index.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function foo() {
                var w = window.open('page2.html', 'foobar', 'target=_blank');
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="#" onclick="foo()">bar</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

page2.html:

```
<html>
    <head />
    <body>
        <a href="www.google.com">google</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

After opening page2 from index.html and middle-clicking the google link, a new tab appears in the window that contains index.html.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

EDIT: Chrome does the same thing.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. Opening new windows or tabs isn't the problem. The new tab being opened in the wrong window is.

Comment: Ah yes, you're right, I missed the italicized part. ;) I don't know what to do about it (and I fear you can't, at least not using specific code and markup), but you can always file a [bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/).

Comment: Ctrl-Click exibits the same issue.  It appears to be a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mozilla team says this behaviour is by design and will not be fixed. See above links for discussion.

Answer (score 0):

This is apparently a known bug, see also the following reports at Bugzilla:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=452332
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=440035
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=654892